# How to call back on all Array methods using alias_method?

Tags: ruby, methods, callback, alias

I want to write a simple call back function based on all methods, just putting an extra word 'hello'. I just learned 'alias' so this feature is what I want to try. Here're the codes:

```
    a = []
class << a
    Array.instance_methods(false).each do |meth|    
            alias_method :old_meth, meth
        define_method(meth) do |*args, &block|
            old_meth *args, &block
            puts "hello"
        end
    end 
end
a.push "good"
```

While running the code, I get the following error:

```
DRBServer.rb:6:in `pack': too few arguments (ArgumentError)
```

Then I think it's because of the 'pack' function, so I filter 'pack' function as follows:

```
Array.instance_methods(false).each do |meth|    
if meth != :pack
....
end
```

Then it complains about another function 'drop_while'...

```
DRBServer.rb:7:in `drop_while': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

I know the problem must be the way of passing parameters (*args, &block), but if I just pass parameters to one method using this way, then it works correct. As follows:

```
a = []
class << a
          alias_method :old_push, :push
          define_method("push") do |*args, &block|
               old_push *args, &block
               puts "hello"
          end 
end

a.push "good" => [output "hello"]
```

I'm really confusing and appreciates your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
alias_method :old_meth, meth
```

You alias *every* original method as `old_meth` (using the same name for all of them), so the original methods are not preserved, except for the last one iterated. Either generate `old_<method>` names dynamically, or use some other storage (such as Hash) for storing original methods.

Comment: Thanks Mladen! I changed the codes as you mentioned and it works.